# passing parameter to onSuccess function of AjaxOption

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to update the `innerHTML` of a `span` of `id="commentcount@(post.PostId.ToString())"` after successful submission of a form using `onSuccess` function of `AjaxOption`. For that I am passing parameter to the javascript fucntion to be passed to `onSuccess` option. But javascript fucntion is not being called after ssubmission of the form.
here is `onSuccess` option:

```
OnSuccess ="UpdateCount("+@post.PostId+")"
```

and the javascript fucntion:

```
function UpdateCount(PostId)
    {
        var count;
        var update = document.getElementById("commentcount" + PostId).innerHTML;
        if (like == "") {
            count = 0;
        }
        else {
            count = parseInt(update);
        }
        count += 1;
        document.getElementById("commentcount" + PostId).innerHTML = count;
    }
```

Please help me to figure out how can I pass parameter to `onSuccess` javascript option.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or any other framework to submit the form via AJAX or is it plain JS? Any chance you could create a jsFiddle to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: I am using Asp.Net and MVC with Razor view engine